# Which case of pronouns should be used with prepositions?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns

I have a problem in understanding the role about which form of pronouns should be used with prepositions

> I am going to school with him

Comment: Let me understand your problem clearly. So you want to know which case of a pronoun is needed after a preposition. Right? We need a accusative case of pronoun after a preposition.

Comment: Yes, the right form is "with **him**", not "with **he**".

Answer (score 3):

There are many kind of pronouns like personal pronoun, demonstrative pronoun, relative pronoun etc. Pronouns regardless of their classification can occur after preposition. The thing that needs to take care of is the case of a pronoun that comes after a preposition.

**Notes from Fowler's Modern English Usage -**

> After a preposition the objective (accusative) form of a pronoun, where it differs from the subjective (nominative) form, must always be used.
>
> **For example -**
>
> > i) Believe in *him*.
> >
> > ii) Between *us*.
> >
> > iii) For *them*.
>
> This is especially important when two pronouns are linked by *and* or *or*. For example -
>
> > Between you and *me* (not *I*)
> >
> > A gift from my brother and *me* (not *I*)
> >
> > asked if there was any chance of *him* (not *he*) and Gina reconciling.

Some more examples -

*Who* is a relative or interrogative pronoun. *Who* is the subjective form, *whose* is the possessive form, and *whom* is the objective form. Now if I want to use that pronoun after a preposition, the objective form *whom* should be used according to the rule stated by Fowler.

> To *whom* does it matter? (not *who* or *whose*)

*Everybody* is a indefinite pronoun. There is no difference between subjective form and objective form. In both form it's *everybody*, but the possessive form is *everybody's*

> It's clear to *everybody*.

The demonstrative pronoun *those* has no difference in subjective form and objective form.

> It concerns to *those* who failed to obtain the minimum qualifying marks.

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 1):

IAs the PO's question "what types of pronouns should be used with prepositions??" indicates that he is familiar with the types of pronouns, I don't need to go into detail.

We usually use an objective pronoun after a preposition, which serves as the  object of a preposition or the object of a verb or a sentence. In the above sentence, the pronoun "him" is the object of the preposition "with". The objective pronouns are: me, us, you, him, her, them, it, whom, etc.  A few examples are as follows:

- He was sitting with me. (The pronoun is the object of the preposition)
- I wrote a letter to him. (the pronoun "him" is the object of the verb "wrote").
- He depends too much on him.

Sometimes, we use prepositions before possessive pronouns in the construct of the following types of sentences:

- The door of my house is broken.
- I go to to school with his brother.

In these sentences, my, and his are possessive pronouns.

Comment: With the exception of "friend of mine", the other statements, the possessives are considered possessive adjectives/determiners not possessive pronouns and are also not the object of the preposition.